# Add hours to a Date object with only time and AM/PM displayed?

Tags: javascript, html, date, datetime, time

How to add hours to a Date object?

This was a clock ONLY that is 1 hour ahead. Can be customized to whatever amount of hours you need.

This works in all time zones.

If you want to add more hours just change the output for each hour 0-23

````
```
 <script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
    DisplayCurrentTime();
};
function DisplayCurrentTime() {
    var date = new Date();
    var a = date.getHours() == 0 ? "1" : "" ;
    var b = date.getHours() == 1 ? "2" : "" ;
    var c = date.getHours() == 2 ? "3" : "" ;
    var d = date.getHours() == 3 ? "4" : "" ;
    var e = date.getHours() == 4 ? "5" : "" ;
    var f = date.getHours() == 5 ? "6" : "" ;
    var g = date.getHours() == 6 ? "7" : "" ;
    var h = date.getHours() == 7 ? "8" : "" ;
    var i = date.getHours() == 8 ? "9" : "" ;
    var j = date.getHours() == 9 ? "10" : "" ;
    var k = date.getHours() == 10 ? "11" : "" ;
    var l = date.getHours() == 11 ? "12" : "" ;
    var m = date.getHours() == 12 ? "1" : "" ;
    var n = date.getHours() == 13 ? "2" : "" ;
    var o = date.getHours() == 14 ? "3" : "" ;
    var p = date.getHours() == 15 ? "4" : "" ;
    var q = date.getHours() == 16 ? "5" : "" ;
    var r = date.getHours() == 17 ? "6" : "" ;
    var s = date.getHours() == 18 ? "7" : "" ;
    var t = date.getHours() == 19 ? "8" : "" ;
    var u = date.getHours() == 20 ? "9" : "" ;
    var v = date.getHours() == 21 ? "10" : "" ;
    var w = date.getHours() == 22 ? "11" : "" ;
    var x = date.getHours() == 23 ? "12" : "" ;

    var am = date.getHours() <= 10 ? "AM" : "";
    var pm = date.getHours() == 11 ? "PM" : "";
  var pma = date.getHours() == 12 ? "PM" : "";
  var pmb = date.getHours() == 13 ? "PM" : "";
  var pmc = date.getHours() == 14 ? "PM" : "";
  var pmd = date.getHours() == 15 ? "PM" : "";
  var pme = date.getHours() == 16 ? "PM" : "";
  var pmf = date.getHours() == 17 ? "PM" : "";
  var pmg = date.getHours() == 18 ? "PM" : "";
  var pmh = date.getHours() == 19 ? "PM" : "";
  var pmi = date.getHours() == 20 ? "PM" : "";
  var pmj = date.getHours() == 21 ? "PM" : "";
  var pmk = date.getHours() == 22 ? "PM" : "";
  var ama = date.getHours() == 23 ? "AM" : "";

  var minutes = date.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + date.getMinutes() : date.getMinutes();


  
    time = a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k + l + m + n + o + p + q + r + s + t + u + v + w + x + ":" + minutes + " " + am + pm + pma + pmb + pmc + pmd + pme + pmf + pmg + pmh + pmi + pmj + pmk + ama;
    var lblTime = document.getElementById("lblTime");
    lblTime.innerHTML = time;
};
````

One hour from now is: < span id='lblTime'>

Comment: @jabaa What is the correct way without 'date'

Comment: Obligatory https://gist.github.com/timvisee/fcda9bbdff88d45cc9061606b4b923ca

Comment: usually use my own date or time classes when I only need date or time. The Date object adds more complexity and doesn't solve any serious problems. The math is very simple if you don't have to consider timezones.

Comment: *"This works ..."*: if it works, it is not a question. It looks like your post is answering some question that wasn't asked. Voting to close. In the mean time here is something about [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Comment: This "question" doesn't contain a question, nor is it a reasonable example of how to add an hour to the time and display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why your logic very complicated. its a simple code bro.

```js
var datetime = new Date();
const timeFormat = { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit'}
console.log("Before: ", datetime.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', timeFormat));

//ADD n Hour
datetime.setHours(datetime.getHours()+1); 
console.log("After: ", datetime.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', timeFormat));
```

result
Before:  09:00 PM
After:  10:00 PM

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of libraries that can accomplish this for you. [date-fns](https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-fns) is one. For instance, the function https://date-fns.org/v2.29.3/docs/intlFormat. JavaScript Dates have a number of issues and aren't super easy to work with. There is a new [api](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/index.html) in the works to deal with many of these issues.

For a relatively simplistic implementation for adding an hour to a date, this should do the trick:

As described on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

> `Date` objects contain a `Number` that represents milliseconds since 1
> January 1970 UTC.

The `valueOf` function will return the millisecond representation of the `Date` object. Add to that the number of milliseconds you are interested(in this case 60(minutes in hour) * 60(seconds in minute) * 1000(milliseconds in second)) in and then pass that number to the date constructor.

```js
const date = new Date(Date.now());
const hourInMilliseconds = 60 * 60 * 1000;
const datePlusHour = new Date(date.valueOf() + hourInMilliseconds);

const dateHour = datePlusHour.getHours();
const amPmString = Math.floor(dateHour / 12) > 0 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
let dateHourString;
if (dateHour === 0) {
  dateHourString = '12';
} else {
  const twelveHour = dateHour % 12;
  dateHourString = (twelveHour < 10 ? '0' : '') + twelveHour;
}

const dateMinuteString = (datePlusHour.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' : '') + datePlusHour.getMinutes();
console.log(date, datePlusHour);
console.log(`${dateHourString}:${dateMinuteString} ${amPmString}`);
```

Comment: This displays the entire date not formatted as just time clock.

Comment: @Lakewood Your question was how do you add an hour to a date? Add an hour to the date and then run your function to convert it to am/pm time.

Answer (score 0):

you can use combine multiple function for that

like this

```js
const addHours = (date, hours) => 
 new Date(date.getTime() + 3600 *1000 * hours)

const formatDate = date => {
  const hour = date.getHours()
  const minutes = date.getMinutes()
  const isAm = hour < 13
  return `${(isAm? hour: hour - 12).toString().padStart(2, '0')}:${minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0')} ${isAm? 'AM': 'PM'}`
}

const addHourAndFormat = (date, hours) => formatDate(addHours(date, hours))

const date1 = new Date('2022-11-15 14:54:00')
const date2 = addHours(date1, 5)

console.log(formatDate(date1))
console.log(formatDate(date2))

console.log(addHourAndFormat(date1, 13))
```